# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=app:// }

Tags: android, webview

I receive the following error message:

> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=app:// }

I have tried a number of different methods but with no success. Here is the code I am using:

```
if (url.startsWith("app://")) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
     intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
     startActivity(intent);
     return true;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Open a http link or something different?

Comment: instead of `startActivity(intent)` use `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Open With..."));`

Comment: post a complete code where form you are getting url value

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view app on google play store, please try this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to install the app you intend to use on the Intent.
For example, different markets or apps
That was the solution for me
You can also use this method to make sure :

```
 private Boolean isBazaarInstalled() {
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    try {
      manager.getPackageInfo("com.farsitel.bazaar", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
```

and use it like this :

```
if (isBazaarInstalled()) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          intent.setData(Uri.parse("bazaar://collection?slug=by_author&aid=" + "602737144978"));
          intent.setPackage("com.farsitel.bazaar");
          startActivity(intent);
        } else {
          Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.bazar_not_installed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```